# Adobe Premier Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, adobe

I have a MacBook Air 13" (Late - 2013) Haswell. Running Mavericks 10.9.4 and I want to start learning advanced video editing but will my Mac run Adobe Premier Pro well? I tried Final Cut Pro and it worked OK but still was laggy and iMovie does not do the job I want to do, it's not advanced enough.

Some say I should have 8Gb of ram, is that true? I'm not going to do the most advanced of sorts but just custom intros, texts, minor particle effects and so on.

Because if it won't work well I don't want to pay for Premier Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Adobe Premiere Pro support site, you'll need this :

- Multicore Intel processor with 64-bit support
- Mac OS X v10.8 or v10.9
- 4 GB of RAM (8 GB recommended)
- 4 GB of available hard-disk space for installation; additional free space required during installation (cannot install on a volume that uses a case-sensitive fi le system or on removable fl ash storage devices)
- Additional disk space required for preview files and other working files (10 GB recommended)
- 1280 x 800 display
- 7200-RPM hard drive (multiple fast disk drives configured for RAID 0 recommended)
- QuickTime 7.6.6 software required for QuickTime features
- Optional: Adobe-certifi ed GPU card for GPU-accelerated performance
- Internet connection and registration are necessary for required software activation, validation of subscriptions, and access to online services.

So your MBA should be good for it. Just be patient when rendering previews ;)

Comment: Just a common curtsey..when answering a question, if you found it clear and good, give the OP some points :)

Comment: @Buscar웃 : you're right, but as it is just an almost googled answer, I don't know if the question worth it or not. See what I mean ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't run on my macbook air 2013